# The type or namespace name 'DrawableGameObject' could not be found?

Tags: c#, xna, class-design, xna-4.0

I've been working on a XNA project for a class I'm taking. I had an issue with a class that I was making for the "Bad guys" which are snowmen (the class is called Snowman.cs). I cannot get the program to compile and it's driving me crazy. Someone helped me out with what I think is some solid code for the Snowman.cs class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using CameraViewer;

namespace MGH10_Skybox
{
    public class Snowman : DrawableGameObject 
    {
        private Camera cam = new Camera();

        Model snowMan;
        Matrix[] snowManMatrix;

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            //snowMan = Content.Load<Model>( "Models\\snowman" );
            snowManMatrix = new Matrix[snowMan.Bones.Count];
            snowMan.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(snowManMatrix);
        }

        public void DrawSnowMan(Model model, GameTime gameTime)
        {
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
            {
                Matrix world, scale, translation;

                scale = Matrix.CreateScale(0.02f, 0.02f, 0.02f);
                translation = Matrix.CreateScale(0.0f, 0.7f, -4.0f);

                world = scale * translation;

                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    effect.World = snowManMatrix[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * world;

                    effect.View = cam.viewMatrix;
                    effect.Projection = cam.projectionMatrix;
                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                }

                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            DrawSnowMan(snowMan, gameTime);
        }

    }
}
```

My issue is that I keep getting a compiler error that says "The type or namespace name 'DrawableGameObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)".

I have tried doing all kinds of research on google and I get almost no results for DrawableGameObject, but anything that does talk about it (or at least says it in the page preview) usually ends up using *DrawableGameComponent* instead.

I've tried using DrawableGameComponent, but then I get even more compiler errors which lead me to believe that it truly is **not** what I'm looking for. Specifically, the error states that "DrawableGameComponent does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments" (which goes against how my class and its calls were constructed).

The one gleam of hope that I had was that 'DrawableGameObject' is supposedly a .net 4.0 class, and I had been using XNA 3.1 w/ Visual C# 2008 (which does not support 4.0 apparently). So I downloaded XNA 4.0 and Visual C# Express 2010 with high hopes that crashed and burned when I went to change the target Framework only to find the option completely grayed out (even when starting a completely new project).

All help is **GREATLY** appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you will actually want "DrawableGameComponent" instead, as I couldn't find anything about a "DrawableGameObject" class.  The error you're getting when trying to inherit from DrawableGameComponent can be fixed by calling the base constructor with the appropriate parameter during your classes constructor, as shown below:

```
public Snowman(Game game) : base(game)
{
   //Whatever goes here!
}
```

"game" in the base constructor is supposed to be the Game object that the DrawableGameComponent is attached to.

**Edit:**

Based on your latest comment, I'd recommend adding this constructor to your class (that is, replace what I previously suggested with this constructor):

```
public Snowman(Game game, Model snowman) : base(game)
{
    this.snowman = snowman;
}
```

And in your Game1.cs, in your LoadContent function or wherever you're currently calling "snowMan = Content.Load ( "Models\snowman");", try this instead:

```
snowMan = new Snowman(this, Content.Load<Model>("Models\\snowman");
```

This will create a new Snowman instance with the "Model snowman" field initialized.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the response and the research that you've done as well! I'm a little confused by your suggestion. I couldn't get that to work properly though. My main game file is called Game1.cs, so I am to insert "Game1.cs" where you have "game" correct?

Comment: You should be able to just add that code to your class as it is written.  "Game" refers to the "Game" class that is part of the XNA framework, and "game" is just the instance of that.  In your Game1.cs file, whenever you want a new Snowman instance, you'll just write:

"Snowman snowman = new Snowman(this);"

(sans quotes) where "this" is referring to your Game1 class, which inherits from the Game class.

Comment: Hi Ben, that makes more sense thank you. Apparently I'm still doing something wrong, when I try to call a new instance in the Game1.cs class, I was getting an error of not being able to change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member (on the Snowman Draw() method). By changing protected override void Draw to public override void draw in my Snowman class, I'm now down to Keyword 'this' is not available in current context. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're doing the "new Snowman(this)" outside of a function in your class.  You'll want to write "Snowman snowman;" with the rest of your member variables at the top of your class.  Later on, in LoadContent() or some other function is where you'll want to write "snowman = new Snowman(this);".

Comment: Yes thank you, I got that part shortly after posting :) and now Ben, I'm so sorry, I have one more question for you. Everything is seemingly ok, except there is a warning in my Snowman class that my Model snowMan is not assigned and will therefore be null. I notice that I cannot use the line of code: snowMan = Content.Load<Model> ( "Models\\snowman"); and the DrawableGameComponent doesn't seem to have anything similar to that. Attempting to use that line in the Game1.cs will give "cannot implicitly convert type...Model to Snowman" any thoughts on loading and drawing the model?

Comment: The problem is that you're never actually assigning a value to your "Model snowman", so it will never have a value.  Check the edit to my original answer  for help with the rest.

Comment: Thank you very much Ben, I really appreciate the help! Unfortunately, I still don't have it working (*slams head against the wall*), but it's for a different reason now. I can tell what you've given has the components that I'm looking for and I can't tell you how grateful I am that you continued to answer my questions  despite the fact that there were about 500 of them lol. Thank you again, I'll make sure to post once more when I have it working :D

Answer (score 0):

So... if you can't find the class, make your own!

Anywho, I guess DrawableGameObject was supposed to make it easy to update and draw different types of objects in the game engine, but if you're using it only for the snowman (which I would guess since you're not mentioning other code not working..) you might as well not have it!

So remove the inheritance for that class, and remove the override from those methods. Hide the DrawSnowMan method (i.e. make that private), and make the LoadContent and Draw public, and call them from respective methods in your Game class!

Also, I would suggest building in a mechanism to draw your snowman on different locations, or if you want to have multiple instances of the SnowMan class, move the Model somewhere else (they are gonna share it, so you could save some memory by not duplicating it unnecessarily).

Hope I helped some, although if you were looking for an answer that involved finding the DrawableGameObject class then sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response Niko. I will try what you suggested

Comment: Niko, I've setup the Snowman class as you've described and I think that I only have one more issue... The Model snowMan shows a warning that it's not assigned to and will therefore always have it's null value. Am I supposed to assign it in the main Game1.cs file or in that same Snowman class?

Comment: Well, I can see that you commented out the line that assigns the snowman variable, perhaps that error would go away if you uncomment that line?